# Odoo 10 - Overriding unlink method

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am overriding unlink method from account.invoice to allow delete last raised invoice.

This is my code:

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        for invoice in self:
            if invoice.state not in ('draft', 'cancel'):
                raise UserError(('You cannot delete an invoice which is not draft or cancelled. You should refund it instead.'))
            elif invoice.move_name:
                if invoice.journal_id.sequence_id:
                    sequence_id = invoice.journal_id.sequence_id
                    last_assigned_number = sequence_id.next_number_do_not_increase() - 1
                    last_assigned_number_text = sequence_id.get_next_char(last_assigned_number)
                    if last_assigned_number_text == invoice.move_name:
                        invoice.journal_id.sequence_id.write({'number_next': last_assigned_number})
                    else:
                        raise UserError(('You cannot delete an invoice after it has been validated (and received a number). You can set it back to "Draft" state and modify its content, then re-confirm it.'))
        return super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink()
```

So far so good,

My specific question is on the last line, when I ran this code flows goes so no UserErrors are raised in this ROUTINE, but then it runs super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink() and it executes the old code form account_invoice.py:

```py
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    for invoice in self:
        if invoice.state not in ('draft', 'cancel'):
            raise UserError(_('You cannot delete an invoice which is not draft or cancelled. You should refund it instead.'))
        elif invoice.move_name:
            raise UserError(_('You cannot delete an invoice after it has been validated (and received a number). You can set it back to "Draft" state and modify its content, then re-confirm it.'))
    return super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink()
```

Which raises an error, how should I rewrite this unlink method so this does not happen?

Comment: can you attach the error with your question?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this work try it.

Call the super of invoice it self.

```
           super(invoice.AccountInvoice, self).unlink()
```

Don't forgetto import invoice first.

Comment: That's neither recommended nor necessary to extend the class. OP is using the proper inheritance method.

Comment: I finally did this: super(invoice.AccountInvoice,self).unlink(), which forces to use the super from the inherited -original- method. I keep models.Model. I suspect that your answer might work too.

Comment: It was my first idea to do what you did.  i'm using my phone didn't have my PC to try it. but again very useful question

Answer (score 1):

If you are **overriding** the original method rather than *extending* (adding onto) it, then you just need to avoid calling `super`.

```
    # replace this line to prevent the original method from running
    # return super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink()

    # this will unlink (delete) all records in the recordset without
    # calling the original method (which is what super does)
    return self.unlink()
```

Comment: But I still want to run the parent method of the original method.

Comment: @usk70 Why? It will continue to throw errors based on the original method. It seems like it will basically render your custom method useless.

Comment: note that I said: parent method of the original method, which is the grandparent of our overriding method.

Comment: @usk70 What is the grandparent method doing? It may be necessary to incorporate it into your method directly.

Answer (score 0):

import the prefered overrided method

```
from odoo.addons.account.models.account_invoice import AccountInvoice as BaseAccountInvoice
```

then call it

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    @api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        return super(BaseAccountInvoice,self).unlink()
```